"Windows tilted open to the chill day"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part I, Aberfan, chapter 5)

There are now five embalming stations around him doing the same. The formaldehyde fumes he usually enjoys are intense, even with all the leaded windows tilted open to the chill day.

I think to has a locative meaning there - tilted open to outside, where there is a chill day. It doesn't have a temporal meaning in this context, right?

Because a tilt window is a kind of window. To open it, you tilt it. There are all sorts of variations, ones that only tilt inwards or others that only tilt outwards. And the tilting can vary too: from the bottom, the top or side. European-style ones are called: turn and tilt windows. Please do google these windows. Instead of saying tilted open to the outside, she's literary and makes it: tilted open to the chill day [cold-ish air].

You can't tilt a window open to Friday, so a temporal meaning wouldn't make much sense.

In this context, open to the chill day is circumlocution for wide open to the cold air outside (necessary because  with so many dead bodies being treated at once, the formaldehyde fumes would otherwise be overpowering). That may be artistic license, though. I don't think the continental style "tilt" double-glazed windows appeared in Britain / Wales until long after Aberfan.

@FumbleFingers - I think, from earlier questions, that this is happening in a church? 19th century leaded church windows sometimes have a panel in the centre that can be tilted open.

@KateBunting: I just assumed it was a mortuary. Why would half-a-dozen bodies (out of well over 100 dead) be embalmed / treated with formaldehyde in a church?

Like this. Wikipedia says "A makeshift mortuary was set up in the village's Bethania Chapel".

Actually, here are all the grim details. They did use the nearby church as a temporary mortuary, and within 2 days, 400 embalmers had arrived. It doesn't explicitly say they did the embalming in the church, but I suppose it's implied.

@ Maciej Stachowski; "You can't tilt a window open to Friday"- My problem was: does "to" belong to "open" or to "the chill day", that is, does "to the chill day" have a temporal meaning or doesn't it, e.g. "to the day" does have a temporal meaning.

No, it doesn't. The chill day just means the chilly weather that there was that day.

I don't think it is locative or directional (i.e. indicating that the windows are tilted out)  but a poetic sense of open to: the windows are "open to" (allowing in) what the day has brought: chilly weather. Compare open to the weather, a fixed phrase.

What @TimR said. The to in open to the chill day here effectively introduces an "adverb of agent / beneficiary" (the "open" window state allows the cold air of "the chill day" to enter, as well as allowing the fumes to escape). Compare open to all comers (anyone can enter).

@ Kate Bunting: "No, it doesn't". - "to the day" or "to this day" does have a temporal meaning - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-this-day. I'm not sure if you are referring to "to the/this day", though.

I think this is simply a poetic variation of the stock phrase open to the weather.
day does not have a calendar sense there, but refers to what the day has brought (chill); and "open to" does not have a directional sense indicating that the windows tilt outward.
The windows are tilted open and admitting the chill.
If a theater's doors are "thrown open to the crowd" they could still be opening inward, not outward. It means that they are opened to admit the crowd.
